# IE mobile any documentation what supports?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css, mobile

I was looking for some time what IE mobile on Windows Phone supports?

I couldn't find any
Can anoyone help me? thank you

**EDIT**

I'm sorry for this question, it was bad to ask like that, waste time this great community. It was inappropriate to write with language like that.

I know Everything I need about internet explorer at this moment.
If I would as for upvote this question would be greatfull.

Sorry

Comment: Did you try with http://caniuse.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your best bet is http://caniuse.com/, it details support across browsers.